# Error in { : task 1524 failed - "cannot open the connection"

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I can't seem to find any help on this problem on the internet.

I'm running a function in parallel using the 'foreach' and 'doParallel' packages. This function takes a trained model and two data frames as input, makes predictions, then shuffles the values for one of the variables, and makes predictions again. It calculates the RMSE for each variable and returns the ones that increase after shuffling. It takes quite a long time, so I have to run it in parallel. Even so, it still takes about 2 hours per model.

It doesn't seem to be an issue with the function's code itself, maybe the input, because I've run it before without issue, and I checked my log file after the error, and it processed all of the variables. I have 5 models that I want to run this function on. I ran it on one model first, and saved the results. Now that it worked, I want to apply it to the remaining models.

Something seems to be going wrong after the foreach loop is done processing, since the log file indicates all variables were analyzed. But what I don't get is that the traceback indicates the error is occurring INSIDE the loop.

Thanks in advance for any help with this issue. Let me know if I'm not clear about anything. I'm running Windows7 and R version 3.1.

Here is the error:

```
Error in { : task 1524 failed - "cannot open the connection" 
10 stop(simpleError(msg, call = expr)) 
9 e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data) 
8 foreach(variable = names(newdata), .export = c("calc.rmse", "catf", 
    "start.timer", "stop.timer"), .combine = "rbind") %dopar% 
    {
        baseline = NULL ... at feature_selection.R#53
7 FUN(c("pH", "Ca", "P", "Sand")[[1L]], ...) 
6 lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) 
5 sapply(names(amodels[2:length(amodels)]), analyze.features, newdata = test.data, 
    newoutcomes = test.outcomes) at script.R#59
4 eval(expr, envir, enclos) 
3 eval(ei, envir) 
2 withVisible(eval(ei, envir)) 
1 source("~/%FILEPATH%")
```

Here is the code for the function in question:

```
analyze.features = function(newdata, newoutcomes, model.name) {
   model = amodels[[model.name]]
   file = "data/shuffled_data.csv"

   if(!file.exists(file)) {
      cat("Creating shuffled data frame...\r\n")
      shuffled.data = as.data.frame(sapply(newdata, shuffle))

      cat("Writing shuffled data frame to disk...\r\n")
      write.csv(shuffled.data, file)
   } else {
      cat("Reading shuffled data from file...\r\n")
      shuffled.data = read.csv(file)
   }

   # Send output to a log file.
   writeLines("", "log.txt")

   start.timer("About to enter parallelization...")
   cat("Time is: ", format(Sys.time(), "%a %b %d %X %Y"), "\r\n")

   output = foreach(variable = names(newdata), .export=c("calc.rmse", "catf", "start.timer", "stop.timer"), .combine="rbind") %dopar% {
      baseline = NULL
      shuffle = NULL

      sdata = newdata

      # Write to log file.
      catf("Analyzing ", variable)

      sdata[[variable]] = shuffled.data[[variable]]

      baseline[[variable]] = suppressWarnings(calc.rmse(predict(model, newdata=newdata), newoutcomes))
      shuffle[[variable]]  = suppressWarnings(calc.rmse(predict(model, newdata=sdata), newoutcomes))

      cbind(baseline=baseline, shuffle=shuffle)
   }

   stop.timer("Total time to analyze features")

   save.df(output, paste("RMSE_", model.name, sep=""))

   # Reduce list of kept features.
   keep = row.names(output)[which(output[,2] - output[,1] > 0)]

   rm(output, shuffled.data)
   beep(1)
   return(keep)
}
```

Comment: I have the same error you mention. Nevertheless, my function works in some computer but not in others. I really don't understand what is happening, because the error is not of a particular object or function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work. I had to re-write how I was calling this function. Originally, I was calling it through an sapply function.

```
sapply(names(amodels), analyze.features, newdata=test.data, newoutcomes=test.outcomes)
```

Since there are only 5 models, I took them out of the sapply and called analyze.features once for each model, in succession. The job completed without error. I don't really know why; I'm guessing it has something to do with parallelization within an sapply function.